# Using INDIRECT within VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am conducting a series av tests of data in different excel workbooks. It order to not have to change all Workbook names in the formulas used I find it suitable to use `INDIRECT()` and refer to a cell where I can write the workbook name to be tested. This works for the ordinary tasks; however I am having troubles when trying to implement it within a `VLOOKUP`. Currently the `VLOOKUP` looks as folows:

```
=VLOOKUP(B10;[filename.xlsx]Sheet3!$B$5:$E$37;2;FALSE)
```

The variable is the `filename.xlsx` filw for which I would like to use `INDIRECT` refering to a cell with the information of file name. The sheet number and cell range will not vary. I have tried several options but none have been fruitful.

Any input would be much appreciated!

Here below is one of the options I have tried:

```
Cell values:
A1: filename
A2: Sheet1 
A3: $B$5:$E$37
B1: "Word to be found"

=VLOOKUP(B1;INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]" &A2&"'!"&A3);2;FALSE)
```

This returns #N/A error.

Comment: Can you include your usage of `INDIRECT` so we can see where you may be having trouble?

Comment: Yes sure, edited as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your current VLOOKUP is working as intended as `=VLOOKUP(B10;[filename.xlsx]Sheet3!$B$5:$E$37;2;FALSE)`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B10;INDIRECT("["&A1&"]"&A2&"!"&A3);2;FALSE)
```

should do what you require. Remember that the filename must also include the extension, so A1 should contain `filename.xlsx`. Alternatively you could use

```
=VLOOKUP(B10;INDIRECT("["&A1&".xlsx]"&A2&"!"&A3);2;FALSE)
```

if you wish to negate this.

Comment: Thank you @Jonno, unfortunately it still returns the #N/A error... The original VLOOKUP does work as intended.

Comment: @Seb Then your indirect is fine, it just can't find the word you're trying to find. You'd be getting a `#REF!` error if the indirect wasn't working. Check the contents of B10 are actually within your range specified in A3., on the sheet in A2, and the workbook named A1 :)

Comment: You are completely right. I referenced the wrong sheet I noticed now. Thank you very much for your input!